# macbook os recovery fails because disk is locked

Tags: disk-utility, recovery

My mac was unused for a  long time and today I needed it and I powered it up. But boot wasn't completed. I followed the methods to reset the NVRAM, SMC and didn't help.

Disk utility indicated that the hard drive can't be repaired. I booted to single-user mode with 'Cmd+S' and ran 'fsck -fy' at least ten times and returned with the same error message.

I then wanted to see if Reinstalling OS in the Recovery menu would help.

- I pressed Cmd+R right after pressing the power button, selected Reinstall OS X from the recovery menu.
- The system asked me to connect the mac to the Internet which I did.
- The system said it tried to verify if the Macbook is eligible or suitable for reinstall. That must have been successful too.
- The system then proceeded to install Mac OS X Lion - that's what came with the mac.
- Then the system says that the two disks 'recovery disk', and 'Macintosh HD' are 'locked'. Both the options are greyed out and could not be selected. Since I am not able to select the disk, reinstall cannot proceed.

I do not want to erase the disk. I have another macbook pro in our household that works.

Is there a way I can reinstall the OS, or fix the booting problem or the disk problem somehow without losing the files?